# Jekyll serve error(forked a jekyll blog theme and now no projects work)

Tags: jekyll

below is the error message
struggling a lot and giving me headache..

I was trying to make another blog for myself,
so I signed up another account for github and pulled request to my desktop(Macos) by github desktop, then this error comes up on both blogs, please help me out.

```
nakuk@nagug-ui-iMac digitopia01.github.io % bundle exec jekyll serve --force-polling
/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin/jekyll: line 1: require: command not found
/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin/jekyll: line 3: Gem.use_gemdeps: command not found
/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin/jekyll: line 5: version: command not found
/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin/jekyll: line 7: str: command not found
/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin/jekyll: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin/jekyll: line 9: `  str = str.b[/\A_(.*)_\z/, 1]'
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.